# Appending the content of the files in one folder to the files in another folder

Tags: bash

I have two folders and would like the **append** the content of the files in the second folder, to the files in the first folder. There is not one to one match in folders.

```
+ OriginalFolder
  - a.txt
  - b.txt
  + SubFolder
      - c.txt

+ ToBeAppendedFolder
  + a.txt
  + SubFolder
      - c.txt
```

I tried a loop sth like but it didn't help.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec sh -c "cat appendfolder/*.txt >> {}" \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
while read l; do 
    cat "../OriginalFolder/$l" >> "$l"
done < <(find . -name "*.txt" -type f)
```